# Callback issue with jquery/js/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

UPDATE3 and FINAL: SOLVED thanks to Evan and meder!

UPDATE2: I should clarify, I need function `updateFilters (a,b)` to be called, not created. The function exists elsewhere. Sorry for confusion.

The code below does not work as expected - `udpateFilters(a,b)` is being called before `for` loop ends. Changing async to `false` solves the problem, but this does not seem right. Moreover **updateFilters() is called regardless of ajax success.**

What did I do wrong?

```
save (updateFilters(a,b));

function save (cb) {
    $.ajax ({
         url:'save.php',
         data:somedata,
         async:true,
         success: function (response) {
             for (var i in response) {}

             if (typeof cb!='undefined') cb;
    });
}

function updateFilters (a,b) {
//do some stuff here
}
```

ANSWER:
So as meder suggested I change the parameter. This is 2/3 of the answer!

```
save (
    (function (a,b) {
        return function () {
            return updateFilters(a,b);
        }
    })(a,b)
);
```

Now change the following:

```
if (typeof cb!='undefined') cb (); //brackets are important!
```

And good to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the invocation of a function, not a function that should be called at a later point. If you want the latter, do this:

```
save (
   (function(a,b){
      return function() {
        return updateFilters(a,b)
      }
   })(a,b)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to understand the sequence of calls, which function is called when. Can you help?

Comment: Put alerts inside of each function with unique values and when you see those alerts you'll know which functions are called.

Comment: that's my issue. alert from the second return is never called.

Comment: i mean putting alert after return function (){alert ('r1');... never appears

Comment: You are now referencing code that no one is able to see. Please post the modified alert code you have.

Comment: I see what you created... Sorry for misunderstanding, but function updateFilters already exists, it just needs to be used as callback with set parameters upon completion of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update, you never invoke the callback. It's the same as doing

```
x; // does nothing
```

You want to call the callback:

```
cb(); // invoke the function
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize importance of parentheses!